# CSS alignment issue in dynamic Chosen plugin dropdowns

Tags: jquery, css, multi-select, jquery-chosen

[**Example Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/vrwzckav/2/)

I have used the **Chosen** plugin for the multiselect dropdowns.

On initial page, a `dropdown` is already added in `html` view which is `chosen`.

Then if we click on the "`add mitigator`" new dropdowns are getting added.

Now the feature is like this:

- each dropdown has 1 to 14 as options
- If I select an option (say 2) from dropdown 1, then the other two dropdowns will have (2) deselected (disabled) from their option menu.

The issue revolves around the CSS issue of the `div`s where the dropdowns reside.

To produce the issue:

- Visit the fiddle link.
- Click on the "`add mitigator`" link to add two more dropdowns.
- In `dropdown 2`, select all the options one by one, and you will see the `dropdown2` getting extended and hiding behind the `dropdown3`. But it does not happen with `dropdown1`.

How can I sort out this issue?

Comment: Note- questions are often edited to remove content deemed to be 'noise', content which should otherwise be a comment (such as a thanks note to a user who has posted an answer) and to normalize formatting (remove shouting, format code, format links). Do not take this as an affront to you or the question itself, such changes are made (and then accepted by a community vote) in order to both help you as the OP get more and better quality answers, as well as to help future visitors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try following CSS

```
.chosen-container {
  min-height:30px;
  height:auto !important;
}
```

The newly added multiple select drop-down have a div with classname `.chosen-container` which is getting applied height `30px` into element style through the JavaScript.

you need to overwrite that CSS property from your css file.

**I have updated your fiddle** :https://jsfiddle.net/vrwzckav/4/